# Do short surveys belong in conference papers? Or just survey journals?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, paper-submission, review-articles

I was just wondering if a short survey on the literature belongs on a conference paper (10 pages max). Is it an option to submit the short survey (focuses specifically on an area) to a conference and later on the fully developed survey (focuses on all aspects) to a survey journal? Or would it be more prudent to extend it fully (30+ pages) so it belongs on a survey journal paper. The short survey would be on the limitations of a technique frequently used in cloud computing. The extended version would include a more thorough description, taxonomy, use cases, limitations, etc. The landscape in the field changes very quickly, hence my question of whether it belongs in a conference.

More specifically, the conference does not mention that they don't accept surveys. Here's what the conference says:

> IEEE CLOUD is a flagship conference focusing on innovative cloud
> computing across all "as a service" categories, including modeling,
> developing, publishing, monitoring, managing, delivering
> Everything-as-a-Service (XaaS) in the context of various types of
> cloud environments. IEEE CLOUD invites original papers addressing
> all aspects of cloud computing technology i.e., infrastructure,
> applications, management and security solved using technologies of Big
> Data, Artificial Intelligence, High Performance computing, Distributed
> computing etc.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I've never read a good survey paper that is published in a conference.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on the following sentence:

> IEEE CLOUD invites original papers addressing all aspects of cloud computing technology [...]

To my understanding, this excludes survey/review papers because they are no original papers.

---

See also: [What are the differences between these kinds of articles: original, review, letter, and short communication?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59066/what-are-the-differences-between-these-kinds-of-articles-original-review-lett)

---

As @Tripartio explained in his comments, my understanding is not necessarily the same as intended by the description of possible conference contributions. Attitudes may vary to what is understood as original research, see for example: https://bmjopen.bmj.com/content/9/8/e029704

Comment: I disagree. A newly written survey or literature review is most certainly an original paper. A non-original paper is one that has already been published elsewhere.

Comment: @Tripartio, no, I think you are wrong, see for example 1) https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/authorandreviewertutorials/writing-a-journal-manuscript/types-of-journal-articles/10285504, 2) https://tacomacc.libguides.com/c.php?g=373158&p=2522936, 3) https://westcoastuniversitylibrary.libanswers.com/research/faq/295830. These are just three random internet sources, there are plenty more stating the same. Anyway, asking the conference chair to be 100 % sure is a good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the links. You are challenging me to be more rigorous in my comment (and I mean this in the most positive way). So, I would adjust my comment to say that there is a difference in terminology when referring to "original paper". Some editors consider literature reviews or surveys to be "original reserch", others do not. Here is an article that specifically researched this question: https://bmjopen.bmj.com/content/9/8/e029704. Note: "Fifty-two (80%) editors considered systematic reviews [SRs] original research, either for any type of SR (65%) or only for SRs with a meta-analysis (15%)"

Comment: In any case, this is obviously a controversial point where people legitimately differ in terminology. So note that I did not downvote this answer, even though I choose to use the term "original" to include surveys and reviews.

Comment: @Tripartio, interesting. I will make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should email the conference chair (or preferably the track chair, if you have identified a specific conference track for submission) and ask them directly. That is the only way to answer your question. One conference might accept survey articles in one track, and another conference might not accept them for a similarly-themed track. The same goes with a journal. Not all journals accept survey or literature review articles. Unfortunately, the conference or journal description is not always sufficiently clear on this point because most researchers, even senior researchers, who do not right survey articles do not typically think of this special genre when they develop their conference or journal descriptions. So, email the chair (or journal editor) directly and they should clarify you.